# What does the name "Ashido" mean?

Tags: meaning, names

I keep searching around for what it means, since I want to use the name as one of my characters. But the closest I've ever gotten to a translation was Mina Ashido's name being a pun on meaning Acid. And even then I feel like I'm missing alternate, more viable meanings depending on the spelling and their english meanings. Help?

Comment: "Ashido (maybe 芦戸)" has no meaning. The name "Asido" derive from "acid"  because they sound like each other.

Comment: The meaning can only be determined once you give the name in Japanese (i.e. in *kanji*).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even sure if you know about kanji, but there are more than one way to write the surname "Ashido" with Japanese characters. Ashido is not a common surname, and therefore it's not possible to give the "meaning" unless we know the kanji version of it.

Here are two possibilities with the meaning of each kanji.

- 足土 Ashido: 足 = foot, 土 = soil
- 芦戸 Adhido: 芦 = reed (plant), 戸 = door

That said, generally speaking, the meaning of a surname is usually not worth thinking about. It's something we unconditionally inherit from out parents, and almost no one can explain when and how their surname was coined.

Comment: Well I'm referring to a main name. Not surname. A person's given name and what it could mean depending on it's spelling, since I know that there's more than one version of the name out there. I just can't read Japanese, despite grasping basic mechanics. After all, I don't wanna name my character something stupid by mistake :P

Comment: Ashido is extremely unlikely as a given name, and I cannot think of what it could possibly mean or what its kanji could ever look like. If you don't know enough Japanese, you should simply avoid such a given name. (Note that [Mina Ashido](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/芦戸三奈)'s given name is Mina, not Ashido)

Comment: I know Ashido isn't her given name. But she's the most relevant example.

Answer (score -1):

How about **吾獅童** for "Ashido"?

If you allow a long vowel sound of "o" like "oh" or "ō", "ashido" could be written as 吾獅童, which means "I'm a child of a lion", where 吾 means I, 獅 means a lion and 童 means a child or a little boy.

By the way [Nakamura **Shidō** II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakamura_Shid%C5%8D_II) (二代目 中村 **獅童** Nidaime Nakamura Shidō), is a famous Japanese kabuki and film actor.